# Passing image selection from child window to MainPage

Tags: c#, uwp, parameter-passing, parent-child, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP FTP front-end application.  I've created a UserControl that mimics the form of a standard Windows desktop icon (consisting of a StackPanel containing an Image and a TextBlock) which is to be used as a way of displaying saved favorites.  What I'd like is for the user to be able to select any image to be used as the icon for each favorite, but have run into some pretty significant issue with getting this to work, I believe due to the Windows 10 "no access to filesystem" restriction--I haven't figured out that part yet.

As a temporary substitution, I came up with the idea of having a set of icons for the user to select from, all stored within the Assets folder of the application.  I've created an IconSelector page/child window (IconSelector.xaml) that pops up when appropriate, allowing the user to select from 8 different Images.

The issue I'm running into is getting the selected Image back to the parent window (MainPage.xaml).  I thought of just passing an int from child to parent, and then use that int with an enum to indicate the correct image, but I can't figure out how to pass any parameter at all between child and parent.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194684/pass-value-from-child-window-back-to-mainpage) question on SO, but it's for Silverlighbt and doesn't seem to work in UWP (unless I implemented it incorrectly).

Does anybody have any idea on how to accomplish this?  Code (relevant portions) pasted below:

**MainPage XAML**

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image Source="Assets\Red.png" Canvas.ZIndex="200" />
    <Border x:Name="addFtpGrid" Visibility="Visible" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300" Width="600" Height="350" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentRevealBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="3">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Link name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Address" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Username" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Password" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Confirm Password" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBox x:Name="linkNameEntry" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBox x:Name="addressEntry" Text="ftp://" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0" />
            <TextBox x:Name="usernameEntry" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,0" />
            <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordEntry" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,0">
            </PasswordBox>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="confirmPasswordEntry"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,0" LostFocus="ConfirmPasswordEntry_LostFocus" />
            <Viewbox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="5,15,5,0">
                <Image x:Name="imageEntry" Source="Assets/SquircleX.png" Tapped="ImageEntry_TappedAsync" />
            </Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="Click image to change" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Button x:Name="saveNewFtpLink" Click="SaveNewFtpLink_Click" Content="Save Changes" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Canvas>
```

**MainPage C#**

```
private async void ImageEntry_TappedAsync(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IconSelector selector = new IconSelector();
    selector.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(selector_Tapped);


    ShowDialog(selector);

    //List<string> fileTypes = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif", ".tiff", ".ico" };

    //FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    //picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    //picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

    //foreach (string type in fileTypes)
    //{
    //    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(type);
    //}

    //StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    //if(file != null)
    //{
    //    imageEntry.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
    //    Image selectedImage = new Image();
    //    selectedImage.Source = imageEntry.Source;
    //    imageEntry = selectedImage;
    //    imageEntry.UpdateLayout();

    //    imageToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
    //}
}
```

**IconSelector XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="FtpSharp.IconSelector"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FtpSharp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="175" d:DesignWidth="600"
    Background="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="selectionStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel x:Name="iconViewer" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="1100">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpRed.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpOrange.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpYellow.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpGreen.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpBlue.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpPurple.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpPink.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource selectionStyle}">
                <Image Source="Assets\FtpTeal.png" Margin="4" Height="96" Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button x:Name="commitSelection" Content="Save" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10" />
</Grid>
```

**IconSelector C#**

```
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace FtpSharp
{
public sealed partial class IconSelector : Page
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedIcon", typeof(int),
        typeof(IconSelector), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int SelectedIcon
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedIconProperty, value); }
    }

    public IconSelector()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Image_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image tappedImage = (Image)sender;
        Border tappedBorder = (Border)tappedImage.Parent;
        SolidColorBrush blue = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        foreach (Border border in iconViewer.Children)
        {
            border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }

        tappedBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,255));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, regarding the commented out attempt with `FileOpenPicker` - I think it is still worth trying - write a separate question about the problem you have encountered, it should definitely work.

Comment: Will do, it was my intention to go back to that eventually, as I prefer the more customized option, but I found myself getting so hung up on that part I had to step away from it for a bit.  This was the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can either provide the result as a `public` property of the `IconSelector` class, or as `EventArgs` of an event. You already have the `SelectedIcon` property there, so you can use it. To notify the `MainPage` that the selection has occurred, you need to add an event to `IconSelector` - for example `DialogCompleted`:

```
public event EventHandler<int> DialogCompleted;
```

You will trigger this event when the dialog is confirmed by the user:

```
DialogCompleted?.Invoke(this, SelectedIcon);
```

Then within `MainPage`, you need to subscribe to this event:

```
IconSelector selector = new IconSelector();

selector.DialogCompleted += IconDialogCompleted;

ShowDialog(selector);
```

And now get the `SelectedIcon` inside the handler:

```
private void IconDialogCompleted(object sender, int selectedIcon)
{
    //do something with selectedIcon
}
```